# EF create table relation does not exist C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm working with ASP.NET MVC C# and I found the following problem and I really don't know if I'm doing it right or not, it turns out that I create a database with Code First in an API project, but now I'm using the same database of data in a web project creating the model with Entity Framework, I don't want to mix the two projects. In the entire database there is a table related from many to many called CategoriaNegocios, which is the relationship between Categoria and Negocio, so far so good, but when saving the categorias from negocio I get an error that no finds the NegocioCategorias table, so my query is Why do I change the name of the table?

I will leave code used in the API
Class Negocio

```
public class Negocio
    {
        public Guid NegocioId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string RazonSocial { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string NombreComercial { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Categoria> Categoria{ get; set; }
    }
```

Class Categoria

```
public class Categoria
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid CategoriaId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name{ get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Negocio> Negocio{ get; set; }
    }
```

Context

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }
        
        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }

        public DbSet<Negocio> Negocio{ get; set; }
        public DbSet<Categoria> Categoria{ get; set; }
    }
```

DataBase
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtYfJ.png)

Code in Web using EF from database already created
Class Business

```
public partial class Negocios
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Negocios()
        {
            this.Categorias = new HashSet<Categorias>();
        }
        [Key]
        public System.Guid NegocioId { get; set; }
        public string RazonSocial { get; set; }
        public string NombreComercial { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Categorias> Categorias{ get; set; }
    }
```

Class Categorias

```
public partial class Categorias
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Categorias()
        {
            this.Negocios = new HashSet<Negocios>();
        }
        [Key]
        public System.Guid CategoriaId { get; set; }
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public string Descripcion { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Negocios> Negocios { get; set; }
    }
```

Code to add a new negocio

```
var cates = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(negocios.Categorias);
var categorias = await db.Categorias.Where(c => cates.Contains(c.CategoriaId.ToString())).ToListAsync();
negocio.Categorias = categorias;
direccion.Historial = Utils.Utilidad.Historial(direccion, "");
negocio.Direccions = direccion;
negocio.Historial = Utils.Utilidad.Historial(negocios, "");
db.Negocios.Add(negocio);
await db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

In the SaveChangesAsync() it gives the error

Error image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GC6c.png)

Error Stack

> [SqlException (0x80131904): El nombre de objeto 'dbo.NegociosCategorias' no es válido.]
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +3331296 System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +334 System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) +4289 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption, Boolean shouldCacheForAlwaysEncrypted) +514 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.CompleteAsyncExecuteReader(Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption) +237 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalEndExecuteNonQuery(IAsyncResult asyncResult, String endMethod, Boolean isInternal) +890 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.EndExecuteNonQueryInternal(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +288 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.EndExecuteNonQueryAsync(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +177 System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization) +59
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +32
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +62
> System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.d__8.MoveNext() +2574
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +32
> System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.d__39.MoveNext() +595

> [UpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.]
> System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.d__39.MoveNext() +956
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +32
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +62
> System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.d__156`1.MoveNext() +897 System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +32 System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +62 System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.<SaveChangesToStoreAsync>d__154.MoveNext() +491 System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +32 System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +62 System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.<ExecuteAsyncImplementation>d__6`1.MoveNext() +472
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +32
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +62
> System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.d__151.MoveNext() +716

> [DbUpdateException: An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key properties for their relationships. The EntityEntries property will return null because a single entity cannot be identified as the source of the exception. Handling of exceptions while saving can be made easier by exposing foreign key properties in your entity types. See the InnerException for details.]
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +32
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +62
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() +32 EsteticaWeb.Controllers.<Create>d__4.MoveNext() in C:\Users\Carlos Vidal\source\repos\EsteticaWeb\EsteticaWeb\Controllers\NegociosController.cs:93 System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +32 System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +62 System.Web.Mvc.Async.TaskAsyncActionDescriptor.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +92 System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<BeginInvokeAsynchronousActionMethod>b__1(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +22 System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42 System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__0() +80 System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass11_2.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__2() +396 System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42 System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_6.<BeginInvokeAction>b__4() +50 System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +188 System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38 System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginExecuteCore>b__152_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +29 System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +73
> System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +52
> System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39 System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38 System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginProcessRequest>b__20_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +43 System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +73
> System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38
> System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.InvokeEndHandler(IAsyncResult ar) +231
> System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.OnAsyncHandlerCompletion(IAsyncResult ar) +172

I hope you can help me please, I've been stuck on this for a long time.

Comment: You really ought to have the EF model in its own project and then reference that from both of the other application projects. If you already have a model and a database then you're duplicating work the way you're doing it now.

Comment: I thought about having the model in a different project and then depending on it, but in the API I started to use the same context of the individual accounts and I also have tables related to the user table, so when trying to separate the model to another project I ran into that other problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you are duplicating code, don't do it, but that's not the core issue.

The answer is pretty obvious

**you don't have a table called "dbo.NegociosCategorias"**

You have created a many to many relationship table using EF code first approach called "dbo.CategoriaNegocios", EF will create a joining table with the name of both entities and with the suffix s at the end.

You can change the name of this table by using Fluent API:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{

    modelBuilder.Entity<Negocio>()
                .HasMany<Categoria>(s => s.Categorias)
                .WithMany(c => c.Negocios)
                .Map(cs =>
                        {
                            cs.MapLeftKey("NegocioId");
                            cs.MapRightKey("CategoriaId");
                            cs.ToTable("NegociosCategorias");
                        });

}
```

This will change the name of the many to many table to "dbo.NegociosCategorias".

This is one way, the opposite way without changing the table name is to get the name right(obviously), I'm not sure how you end up with a table named "NegociosCategorias" as it should be "CategoriaNegocios" anyways.

I think you should really change the structure of your project, a domain, and a web, everything database related should remain in the domain project, and the web project just reference to the domain project, that way you don't have to duplicate the classes.

I mean it is already confusing to have one project:

```
public class Negocio {
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<Categoria> Categoria{ get; set; }
    ...
}
```

and another project:

```
public partial class Negocios {
    ....
    public virtual ICollection<Categorias> Categorias { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

and why is it even a partial class, you expecting more from other source files?

Comment: As I answered above, I started with the API project that uses individual accounts, therefore I used the same context to create the tables with Code First, in which there are tables related to the AspUsers table, after that I started with the project Web and I thought about creating a third project for the data model, but I found myself stuck with the Identity tables, so in order not to use Code First again, I used EF directly from an existing database and it generated the other classes for me, but I don't understand Why does it generate a relationship table that does not exist?

Comment: can you post your OnModelCreating method of the automatically generated DbContext class in your Web project

Comment: It didn't really generate it, I'm going to take the long way around and try to move the whole context to a new project, for me it's not funny to program the same thing twice, but I'll still apply your example to solve the problems while I'm at it, thank you very much for your help, I hope it works for me, if so I will mark the answer as correct. Greetings.

Comment: yea i think it's worth the time to move the context to a separate project and let your API and Web project reference to it

Comment: Your help solved the initial problem, but I've already made the big change, I left three projects in the solution, WEB, API, DB, and it's now working correctly, thank you very much.